# Reading a binary file in C: ftell returns results that sometimes are off by one

Tags: c, binary

I'm trying to read a binary file that is in the following format:

> number of images [4-byte int]
>
> width [4-byte int]
>     height [4-byte int]
>     grayscale data [width * height bytes]
>     (more elements of the same type)

That's the first function being called:

```
int process_file(const char *filename) {
    FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "r");

    //Get number of images
    unsigned int number_of_images = read_int_from_file(input_file);

    //Allocate memory for all images
    struct image *images = malloc(sizeof(struct image) * number_of_images);

    read_images(images, number_of_images, input_file)
}
```

Here's the `image` structure for anyone wondering:

```
struct image {
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned char *data;
};
```

And that's what `read_int_from_file` does:

```
static unsigned int read_int_from_file(FILE *file) {
    unsigned char chars[4];
    if (fread(&chars, sizeof(char), 4, file) != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read enough bytes!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    //Calculations follow that return right numbers
    return out;
}
```

That's the rest:

```
static int read_images(struct image *images, unsigned int number_of_images, FILE * file) {
    struct image *current_image = images;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++) {
        read_image(current_image++, file)
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static int read_image(struct image *image, FILE *file) {
    static long int expected_position = 4;

    if (ftell(file) != expected_position) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Reading @ %lu when should be @ %lu!",
                ftell(file), expected_position);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned int width = read_int_from_file(file);
    unsigned int height = read_int_from_file(file);

    unsigned int size = width * height;

    unsigned char *data = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    if (data) {
        if (fread(data, sizeof(char), size, file) != size) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        image->width = width;
        image->height = height;
        image->data = data;

        expected_position += 2 * 4 + width * height;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the file pointer is sometimes going ahead when it shouldn't do so, i.e. I'm hitting `ftell(file) != expected_position`. I'm getting it after a good amount of successful reads, but some good time before the end, too.

Does anyone have *any* idea why that may be? I mean, even if the numbers were wrong, that shouldn't happen, should it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MS-DOS end-of-line sequences are Carriage Return, New Line (`CR NL`, `0x0D, 0x0A`), and Unix uses simply New Line (`NL` or `0x0A`).

Change the line

```
FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "r");
```

to

```
FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "rb");
```

Otherwise, the `fread()` function used to translate `CR NL` as `NL`, on Unix systems prior to POSIX standard "IEEE Std 1003.1-1988".

On MS-DOS, Windows and derivatives, it translates `NL` as `CR NL`.

These translations cause your opinion of the file position to differ from `ftell()`'s calculations.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Very stupid of me to forget this could be it.

Comment: I don't follow your second-to-last paragraph. **Absolutely no translation** happens on Unix, as the POSIX standard requires text mode to behave identically to binary mode.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I've been using ```open()``` in preference to ```fopen()``` since 1988.

Comment: Spent 3 days wondering why it's not working and failed to realize that I forgot add 'b' in fopen. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You need to open the binary file as such:

```
//                                   v
FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "rb");
```