Get into a file offset problem fread & ftell problem
I'm doing a C projct on Windows, using VScode and compile my code with gcc.
I get into some offset problem that might be caused by fread() | ftell().
I read 256 counts of data from my binary file.
And the offset should be added 256 ,but I got the result as picture below.
Can someone tell me why would this happen?

my pseudocode:
main()
{
  FILE* myfile;    /*note this is a binaryfile*/
  uint8 buf[300];
  fopen(myfile,"r");
  while(1)
  {
    int offset = ftell(myfile);   /*get my current file offset every loop*/
    int read_cnt = fread(buf , 1 , 256 , myfile);     
    printf("file offset = %d\n",offset);
    printf("readcount = %d\n",read_cnt);
  }
}


This will most likely fix it: fopen(myfile,"r"); -> fopen(myfile,"rb");. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207302/reading-a-binary-file-in-c-ftell-returns-results-that-sometimes-are-off-by-one

For your next question; Don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

You say the handle is a "binaryfile", but it's not. You didn't use the b flag when you opened it to make a binary stream.

@Jabberwocky Thanks for ur reply and the suggestion.

@ikegami thank u i got it ,originally thought they were the same :(

@willy: They are the same on most platforms. However, on Microsoft Windows, you must distinguish between text mode ("r") and binary mode ("rb").
